# What repo do I need to install SVN - Subversion?

Tags: centos, subversion

I am trying to install SVN (subversion) but when I run

```
$yum install svn
```

I just get

```
No match for argument: svn
```

What repository do I need to configure and or add to be able to install this?

EDIT

Here is my repolist

```
AppStream                                                                      CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                                                                  disabled
AppStream-source                                                               CentOS-8 - AppStream Sources                                                                                          disabled
BaseOS                                                                         CentOS-8 - Base                                                                                                       enabled: 1,697
BaseOS-source                                                                  CentOS-8 - BaseOS Sources                                                                                             disabled
PowerTools                                                                     CentOS-8 - PowerTools                                                                                                 disabled
base-debuginfo                                                                 CentOS-8 - Debuginfo                                                                                                  disabled
c8-media-AppStream                                                             CentOS-AppStream-8 - Media                                                                                            disabled
c8-media-BaseOS                                                                CentOS-BaseOS-8 - Media                                                                                               disabled
centos-8.0-updates-media-AppStream                                             CentOS-Updates-AppStream-8.0 - Media                                                                                  disabled
centos-8.0-updates-media-BaseOS                                                CentOS-Updates-BaseOS-8.0 - Media                                                                                     disabled
centosplus                                                                     CentOS-8 - Plus                                                                                                       disabled
centosplus-source                                                              CentOS-8 - Plus Sources                                                                                               disabled
cr                                                                             CentOS-8 - cr                                                                                                         disabled
*epel                                                                          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                                                        enabled: 7,145
epel-debuginfo                                                                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64 - Debug                                                                disabled
*epel-modular                                                                  Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64                                                                enabled:     0
epel-modular-debuginfo                                                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64 - Debug                                                        disabled
epel-modular-source                                                            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64 - Source                                                       disabled
epel-playground                                                                Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - Playground - x86_64                                                           disabled
epel-playground-debuginfo                                                      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - Playground - x86_64 - Debug                                                   disabled
epel-playground-source                                                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - Playground - x86_64 - Source                                                  disabled
epel-source                                                                    Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64 - Source                                                               disabled
epel-testing                                                                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - Testing - x86_64                                                              disabled
epel-testing-debuginfo                                                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - Testing - x86_64 - Debug                                                      disabled
epel-testing-modular                                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - Testing - x86_64                                                      disabled
epel-testing-modular-debuginfo                                                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - Testing - x86_64 - Debug                                              disabled
epel-testing-modular-source                                                    Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - Testing - x86_64 - Source                                             disabled
epel-testing-source                                                            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - Testing - x86_64 - Source                                                     disabled
extras                                                                         CentOS-8 - Extras                                                                                                     disabled
extras-source                                                                  CentOS-8 - Extras Sources                                                                                             disabled
fasttrack                                                                      CentOS-8 - fasttrack                                                                                                  disabled                                                              
teams                                                                          teams                                                                                                                 disabled
teamviewer                                                                     TeamViewer - x86_64                                                                                                   disabled
```

SOLUTION

Looks like I needed to enable my AppStream repo as I went one by one to different repos enabling and running the $yum install svn command.

Comment: Hmm, it works for me on CentOS Linux 8 official docker image.

Comment: The error doesn’t indicate a missing package; `yum` would say “No package svn available.”, not “No match for argument: svn”. But `yum install svn` should work, it pulls in the `subversion` package, which is in the base CentOS repository...

Answer (score 1):

In general you can use `yum whatprovides` to see what package is needed.

eg

```
% sudo yum whatprovides '/usr/bin/svn'
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
subversion-1.7.14-16.el7.i686 : A Modern Concurrent Version Control System
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/svn



subversion-1.7.14-16.el7.x86_64 : A Modern Concurrent Version Control System
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/svn
```

That tells us the package name is "subversion"

If you're not sure of the full path then you can use wildcards (eg `yum whatprovides '*/svn'`) but that will also report other packages that also include svn components (eg `subversion-ruby`).

Comment: this is what I got [root@localhost ~]# yum whatprovides '/usr/bin/svn'
Last metadata expiration check: 0:08:16 ago on Thu 25 Mar 2021 10:10:10 AM EDT.
Error: No Matches found

Comment: I added my repolist in the edits, is there a repo that I need to enable?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `svn` through :

```
sudo yum install subversion
sudo yum install mod_dav_svn
```